# Kurento connection limits

Tags: streaming, webrtc, kurento

Trying to load test Kurento setup (WebRTC video+audio stream served from a browser and a webcam, and received/played by browsers running in Choromium inside Xvfb inside EC2 instances, launched *en masse*). The app used is a slight modification of one-2-many example, while original version of it provides same result.

Until about 800 connected viewers, things work fine, but then connections start failing, like:

```
Fri Jun 17 2016 10:05:31 GMT+0000 (UTC) connecting presenter 4 with viewer 817
Fri Jun 17 2016 10:05:31 GMT+0000 (UTC) connecting presenter 4 with viewer 819
Fri Jun 17 2016 10:05:50 GMT+0000 (UTC) some error connecting presenter 4 with viewer 812 : Error: Request has timed out
Fri Jun 17 2016 10:05:50 GMT+0000 (UTC) some error connecting presenter 4 with viewer 806 : Error: Request has timed out
Fri Jun 17 2016 10:05:50 GMT+0000 (UTC) some error connecting presenter 4 with viewer 807 : Error: Request has timed out
Fri Jun 17 2016 10:05:50 GMT+0000 (UTC) some error connecting presenter 4 with viewer 810 : Error: Request has timed out
Fri Jun 17 2016 10:05:50 GMT+0000 (UTC) some error connecting presenter 4 with viewer 811 : Error: Request has timed out
Fri Jun 17 2016 10:05:50 GMT+0000 (UTC) some error connecting presenter 4 with viewer 809 : Error: Request has timed out
Fri Jun 17 2016 10:05:50 GMT+0000 (UTC) gather candidates error
Fri Jun 17 2016 10:05:50 GMT+0000 (UTC) gather candidates error
Fri Jun 17 2016 10:05:50 GMT+0000 (UTC) gather candidates error
Fri Jun 17 2016 10:05:50 GMT+0000 (UTC) gather candidates error
```

which is, in source,

```
presenter[presenterId].webRtcEndpoint.connect(webRtcEndpoint, function(error) {
                            if (error) {
                                    console_log("some error connecting presenter "+presenterId+
                                            " with viewer "+sessionId+" : "+error);
                                    stop(sessionId);
                                    return callback(error);
                            }
```

so is 800 connections a Kurento's limit? network interface is 10 gbit and it is not loaded at all, traffic is <1gbit/s. machine is a 16 core Xeon with 128Gb of RAM.

if i try a simpler machine (4-core Xeon with 32 RAM and 1gbit interface) it works fine until 500 connections, then network and processor load reaches 60% (which is expectable, it should be so) and i don't dare to load it more, but there are no failed connections or anything. i kind of expected at least 2000 to work on a 4x more powerful machine, but it fails on 800...

is scaling above 800 connections possible at all?

Comment: I read about some people complaining on increased delays on a lot lower loads. I can't confirm that, delays keep low until the thing breaks. Processor load also remains quite low.

Comment: We have the same requirement to broadcast screen to 500+ people at a time, but we are lacking the quality and unable to get results as per expectations. So can you please help us which server configuration needed and how can we use Kurento to develop.

Answer (score 2):

Please look for [elasticRTC](http://www.slideshare.net/LuisLopez235/elasticrtc-how-to-have-your-own-webrtc-cloud-scaling-to-be-billions-in-minutes) if you want to increase scalability using kurento.
Some more [instructions](https://github.com/elasticRTC/elasticrtc-tools) for creating the setup using elasticRTC.